# Why does this function doesn't execute when written inside parent function?

Tags: javascript, php

The function `saveImagePath` doesn' work when it is inside the main function `uploadFile`. However the file gets uploaded successfully. There's no problem in upload. It's all about this nested function. When I execute the following code, everything executes except this `saveImagePath' function.

To verify this, I wrote the trouble causing nested function outside the main function and called it using `$this->saveImagePath` and Lo! It worked. What can be the issue behind this?

Does it have something to do with return statement?

```
function uploadFile($fields){
        $files = $_FILES['photo'];
        $count = count($files['name']);
        if($fields['type'] == "PROFILEPIC"){
            $folderName="userimages/";
        }else{
            $folderName="personalmarkerimages/";
            $transportStopId=$fields['transportStopId'];
        }

        function saveImagePath($imagePath, $transportStopId)
        {
            $db=$this->dbConnect();
            $mySqlQuery = "UPDATE mytablename SET imagePath=:imagePath WHERE filedname=:stopId";
            $stmt=$db->prepare($mySqlQuery);
            $stmt->bindParam("imagePath", $imagePath);
            $stmt->bindParam("stopId", $transportStopId);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        if(gettype($files['name'])=='array'){
            $num=0;
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++) {
                if ($files['error'][$i] === 0) {
                    $target_file='/myaddress/' . $folderName . $files['name'][$i];
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                        echo '{"status": "error", "message": "Not a valid format"}';
                    }else{
                        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                            echo '{"status": "error", "message": "File already exist"}';
                            break;
                        }else if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file) === true) {
                            saveImagePath($target_file, $transportStopId);
                                $num=$i+1;
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo '{"status": "error", "message": "Couldn\'t upload"}';
        }

        if($num==$count){
            echo '{"status": "success", "values": "'.$fields['description'].'"}';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `function` inside `function` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function in a function looks like a class to me, so I have changed your code to be a class:

```
class FileUploader {
    public function uploadFile($fields){
        $files = $_FILES[ 'photo' ];
        $count = count( $files[ 'name' ] );
        if ( $fields[ 'type' ] == "PROFILEPIC" ) {
            $folderName = "userimages/";
        } else {
            $folderName = "personalmarkerimages/";
            $transportStopId = $fields[ 'transportStopId' ];
        }

        if(gettype($files['name'])=='array'){
            $num=0;
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++) {
                if ($files['error'][$i] === 0) {
                    $target_file='/myaddress/' . $folderName . $files['name'][$i];
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                        echo '{"status": "error", "message": "Not a valid format"}';
                    }else{
                        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                            echo '{"status": "error", "message": "File already exist"}';
                            break;
                        }else if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file) === true) {
                            $this->saveImagePath($target_file, $transportStopId);
                            $num=$i+1;
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo '{"status": "error", "message": "Couldn\'t upload"}';
        }

        if($num==$count){
            echo '{"status": "success", "values": "'.$fields['description'].'"}';
        }
    }

    protected function saveImagePath($imagePath, $transportStopId)
    {
        $db=$this->dbConnect();
        $mySqlQuery = "UPDATE mytablename SET imagePath=:imagePath WHERE filedname=:stopId";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($mySqlQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam("imagePath", $imagePath);
        $stmt->bindParam("stopId", $transportStopId);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

and now you can use this like:

```
(new FileUploader())->uploadFile($fields);
```